# ReactJS Icon not changing on button

Tags: reactjs

Using [Friconix](https://friconix.com) icons, I am attempting to change the icon on a button when the state.active changes; however, I am not having any luck:

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/css/dropmenu.css"

class DropMenu extends React.Component{
    state = {active:false}

    toggleActive = () => {
        let newState = {...this.state};
        newState.active = !newState.active;        
        this.setState(newState);
    }
    render(){                             
        let iconName = "fi-xnl" + (this.state.active ? "u" :"r") + "x" + this.props.size + "-three-bars"
        console.log(iconName)
        return(
            <div className="drop-menu" id={this.props.id}>
                <button onClick = {this.toggleActive} disabled={this.props.disabled ? "disabled":""}><i className={iconName}></i></button>                
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default DropMenu
```

Can someone give me a shove here.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible snippet? (codesnadbox or something)  Things are looking fine here..

Comment: Any error or warning in console ?

Comment: None.  Console shows the name of the icon changing and I am certain that both icons exist.

Comment: So `console.log(iconName)` prints the right one?

Comment: Yes - it produces the correct icon name and I have verified that both icons exists.

Comment: `both icons exists.` but different? Maybe a bad copy / paste of the icons? I can't think of any other options.

Answer (score 0):

If the icon is not displayed in the first load (or for any icon displayed dynamically) you have to call the Friconix function `friconix_update();`

https://friconix.com/start/#display-icons